# How can I boot on start up after user force quit my app?

Tags: android

I didn't know this was possible until recently I force quitted an app and when I restarted my phone I found it had a service running in background and the force quit button became unclickable. There are a lot permissions in that app one of them is modify system setting, does it have anything to do with this permission? what methods use this permission? how can I do the same with me app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your app is now in a stopped state because you force stopped it. While in this state, its components are not active and will not run until the user launches the app through the launcher. This is also the case when the app is first installed. That's why it is not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast.

You need to have an Activity that the user can manually launch in order to move your app out of the stopped state.